# Extract Levels from a Factor in R

Tags: r

I have got temperature data, which is stored as "factor", like this:

```
str(TEMPERATURE)
Factor w/ 2387 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 2285 2254 2256 2237 2217 2197 2175 
2162 2143 2143 ..
```

I use

```
TEMPERATURE<-as.numeric(TEMPERATURE)
```

Then, it becomes

```
str(TEMPERATURE)
num [1:39024] 2285 2254 2256 2237 2217 ...
```

I am wondering how to let it show real temperature, rather which levels the data belong to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors are stored internally as integers - specifically, indices in a lookup table. `as.numeric` extracts these integers, which is one of the amusing little quirks of R - this is almost never what someone will intend to do.

Convert first to character, then to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.character(TEMPERATURE))
```